# Почему heroku выдает ошибку "Server Error (500)" при авторизации в приложении на Python/ Django?

Tags: python, django, heroku

Просто адрес страницы открывается нормально. Но где необходима авторизация и в админке отображается эта ошибка.

Логи на heroku

```js
2020-08-24T16:45:31.571361+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.109.218.102 - - [24/Aug/2020:16:45:31 +0000] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.4050.0 Iron Safari/537.36"
2020-08-24T16:45:31.578387+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin" host=damp-beach-23703.herokuapp.com request_id=42a7a97d-1b89-493a-a240-5e155199879e fwd="178.44.136.197" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=301 bytes=226 protocol=https
2020-08-24T16:45:31.955920+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.109.218.102 - - [24/Aug/2020:16:45:31 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.4050.0 Iron Safari/537.36"
2020-08-24T16:45:31.965005+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/" host=damp-beach-23703.herokuapp.com request_id=00d76b1e-f735-4e46-8af2-d092be9099dd fwd="178.44.136.197" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=216ms status=500 bytes=380 protocol=https
2020-08-24T16:51:29.194937+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.97.137.170 - - [24/Aug/2020:16:51:29 +0000] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/tasks/list/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2433 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.4050.0 Iron Safari/537.36"
2020-08-24T16:51:29.195646+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/accounts/login/?next=/tasks/list/" host=damp-beach-23703.herokuapp.com request_id=9f67ef48-6155-4cfb-9aa2-19218fba1b47 fwd="178.44.136.197" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=35ms status=200 bytes=2944 protocol=https
2020-08-24T16:51:49.094044+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.97.137.170 - - [24/Aug/2020:16:51:49 +0000] "POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "https://damp-beach-23703.herokuapp.com/accounts/login/?next=/tasks/list/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.4050.0 Iron Safari/537.36"
2020-08-24T16:51:49.094729+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/accounts/login/" host=damp-beach-23703.herokuapp.com request_id=d28c42b8-4858-45eb-a757-9e0ffba04838 fwd="178.44.136.197" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=184ms status=302 bytes=679 protocol=https
2020-08-24T16:51:49.461463+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.97.137.170 - - [24/Aug/2020:16:51:49 +0000] "GET /tasks/list/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "https://damp-beach-23703.herokuapp.com/accounts/login/?next=/tasks/list/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.4050.0 Iron Safari/537.36"
2020-08-24T16:51:49.461651+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/tasks/list/" host=damp-beach-23703.herokuapp.com request_id=6189371a-801c-4f73-ad83-847c9858fda2 fwd="178.44.136.197" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=197ms status=500 bytes=380 protocol=https
```

Comment: И что мы из этого должны понять? =)

Comment: @ Inventor   а что нужно для того, чтобы понять?)

Comment: Запустить проект локально и посмотреть на что ругается python/django?

Comment: @ Inventor Локально все работает нормально, единственное, в консоли :    Not Found: /favicon.ico
[24/Aug/2020 17:02:31] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 3765
[24/Aug/2020 17:02:35] "GET /tasks/list HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[24/Aug/2020 17:02:35] "GET /tasks/list/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2636
[24/Aug/2020 17:02:40] "GET /accounts/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1447

Comment: возможно не выполнены миграции/django не может подключиться к БД

Comment: @ Inventor миграции выполнялись командой heroku run python manage.py migrate

Comment: после этого была создана учётная запись администратора?

Comment: @Inventor да, через bash был создан createsuperuser и по урлам damp-beach-23703.herokuapp.com/ и herokuapp/tasks - открываются страницы. Но /tasks/list и /admin - где нужна авторизация после введения пароля и user эта ошибка. т.е. приложение открывается на heroku и Server Error 500 появляется именно после входа. Если разлогиться, то на стр. accounts/login/?next=/tasks/list/ остается форма входа, при этом user авторизован слева т.е. можно создавать задачи. Возможно, ошибки в путях  at=info method=GET path="/admin/"   и at=info method=GET path="/"  но пока не знаю как исправить

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, срабатывало ограничение с того же IP, с которого выходило приложение и heroku регистрировал слишком много запросов, поэтому срабатывало ограничение. Позже проблема решилась.